# Whitelist both IPv4 and IPv6 in AWS Security Group

Tags: amazon-web-services, ipv6, ipv4, security-groups, whitelist

I am setting up an SFTP server, I want to white list all the IPs in the Security Group so people can connect to it from anywhere.

At the moment I am adding 2 rules to the Inbound rules, one rule for IPv4 and one for IPv6:

[image]

Is there anyway that I could whitelist both IP versions in one rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both address families require a rule for each. Note the restriction on source that you can provide one of a IPv4 prefix, or an IPv6 prefix, or some other syntaxes that are also only single single address family.

Some networks can get by as IPv6 only, disable v4 and use transition mechanisms. But most public access services available to anyone on the internet need to be dual stack.

Answer (score 1):

Not as far as I know, IPv4 and IPv6 are separate. Why do you think it matters? I've had security groups with dozens of rules.